# Online instant messenger in java

Tags: java, instant-messaging

I really searched online but i did not find what i want.

I have 2 class these are Clint and Server. That connection is working in local.

I want to connect different PC via online.

Example: My laptop will be server and my friend laptop'll be client. But we are not same city.  So we have to use internet.

Here is the codes:
(Parameter of constructor(host) in Client.java is 127.0.0.1)

**Client.java:**

```
    public class Client extends JFrame{

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;
    private Socket connection;

    //constructor
    public Client(String host) {
        super("Gulum Client");
        serverIP = host;
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(userText,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    //connect to server
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){
            showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
        }catch(IOException ioexception){
            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeCrap();
        }
    }


    //connect to server
    private void connectToServer()throws IOException{
        showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),6789);
        showMessage("Connected to: "+ connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    //setup stream and recieve messages
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams are now setup. \n");
    }

    //while chatting with server
    private void whileChatting()throws IOException{
        ableToType(true);
        do{
            try{
                message = (String)input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n " + message );
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFounException){
                showMessage("\n Unknown that object type!");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
    }

    //close the streams and socets
    private void closeCrap(){
        showMessage("\n Closing connections... ");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //send messages to server
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\n CLIENT - " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            chatWindow.append("\n Stopped to sending message!");
        }
    }

    //change or update chatWindow
    private void showMessage(final String m){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatWindow.append(m);
            }
        });
    }

    //gives user permisson to type crap into text box
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Server.java:**

```
public class Server extends JFrame{

private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

public Server(){
    super("Gulum Instant Messenger");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
            userText.setText("");
        }
    });
    add(userText,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);

}
//set up and run server
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
        while(true){
            try{
                //connect and have conversation
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");
            }finally{
                closeCrap();
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//wait for connection, then display information
private void waitForConnection()throws IOException{
    showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connetc... \n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

}

//get stream to send and recieve data
private void setupStreams()throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
}

//during the chat conversation
private void whileChatting()throws IOException{
    String message = "You are now connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        //have conversation
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n"+message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("\n idk wtf that user sent");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

}
//close streams and sockets after you are done
private void closeCrap(){
    showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send a message to client
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject(" SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\n SERVER - " + message);
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: THAT MESSAGE IS NOT SENT!!!");
    }

}
//update chat window
private void showMessage( final String text){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatWindow.append(text);
        }
    });
}

//let user type stuff into their box
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            userText.setEditable(tof);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the problem is that the server needs a web address...

Comment: What kind of web address. Can you explain more pls

Comment: the problem i don't wanna typing each other using by localhost i wanna  chatting for example between different country.

Answer (score 0):

You and your friend will need to access eachother's computers via public facing IPs. If each of your computers is subnetted behind a home router, you may have difficulties accomplishing this.

I would suggest setting up a VPN.

Here is an excellent article on VPN: http://lifehacker.com/5940565/why-you-should-start-using-a-vpn-and-how-to-choose-the-best-one-for-your-needs